# Hadoop map jobs fail with com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I am trying to run analytics using hadoop map-reduce over data stored inside cassandra. For this, I am using the class `CqlInputFormat` available through the maven dependency `cassandra-all`. Currently we have been using 2.0.10 version of this dependency in our production environment. Also, we are using `caassandra-driver-core` having version 2.1.1.

Now, when I submit a simple map-reduce job to my jobtracker, all my mapper tasks fail with the below exception.

Another important thing to note here is that, if I use `CqlPagingInputFormat` available in 2.0.6 of `cassandra-all`, everything works fine. But this input format has been removed in the later versions.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: 10.40.242.174:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection (you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections)))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:65)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:258)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordReader.initialize(CqlRecordReader.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: 10.40.242.174:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection (you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections)))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:103)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:446)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeQuery(SessionManager.java:482)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:88)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.executeAsync(AbstractSession.java:60)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:260)
    ... 9 more
```

Any inputs are most welcome.

Comment: Seems Cassandra is not active or you didn't provide a valid endpoint. Can you post the code ?

Comment: I am using Cassandra v2.0.11 and `caassandra-driver-core` v2.1.4 and have the same issues...when I used `CqlPagingInputFormat`from `cassandra-all` v2.0.5 then it worked fine. Did you solve your problem? Could you share the solution?

Comment: If it is important: I set `InputCQLPageRowSize` to MAX  
`CqlConfigHelper.setInputCQLPageRowSize(job.getConfiguration(), "" + Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

Comment: I managed to fix my problem - it was related to libraries conflict in `$HADOOP_HOME/lib` directory. After removing old libs my job worked OK (nevertheless I am using a fat jar to run my job)

Comment: I removed everithing in `$HADOOP_HOME/lib` then I copied libraries from the original hadoop package.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exactly same problem when using `cassandra-all-2.0.10`, but the problem has been resolved by using the version `cassandra-all-2.0.12`.

I think the correction is in this commit:
[Potentially use non-local hosts in CqlConfigHelper](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/commit/c1d2b86a4cc6e219eee1cd78c582d5dc2ed27234)